# jquery onclick breaking textbox

Tags: jquery, html, textbox, onclick, anchor

I have setup some jQuery that will trigger when an anchor tag is clicked. The idea is that when the anchor tag is clicked a textbox appears. I currently have this working.

My question is what would cause my textbox from becoming unresponsive? When I click into the textboxes the focus get removed. Is there something wrong with the click function that would disable the focus of my textboxes?

Here is the code I have come up with in JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZtMH/3/

The HTML:

```
<div class="main" id="143"><a href="#" class="thelink">Test Text Here</a></div>
<br />
<div class="main" id="145"><a href="#" class="thelink">Test Text Here</a></div>
```

The jQuery:

```
$('.thelink') + $('#143').click(function() {
$('.main') + $('#143').html('<input type="text" id="pername143" /> <input type="button" value="Set Gift" id="submitgiftname" />');
});

$('.thelink') + $('#145').click(function() {
$('.main') + $('#145').html('<input type="text" id="pername145" /> <input type="button" value="Set Gift" id="submitgiftname" />');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on input box it actually getting propagated to parent. on parent click it re-adding html

Unbind click event will solve your problem. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZtMH/4/)

```
$('.thelink') + $('#143').click(function() {
   $('.main') + $('#143').html('<input type="text" id="pername143" /> <input type="button" value="Set Gift" id="submitgiftname" />');
    $(this).unbind('click');
});

$('.thelink') + $('#145').click(function() {
   $('.main') + $('#145').html('<input type="text" id="pername145" /> <input type="button" value="Set Gift" id="submitgiftname" />');
    $(this).unbind('click');
});
```

Comment: two improvements:
1) IDs should be unique in a document, so dont find the element by a class selector
2) using on and off instead because of "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document." see jquery docs

Comment: That worked very well. I really appreciate your help. I wasn't aware that I had to unbind this.

Comment: since event bubble from child to parent if you does not unbind your click event will get fired again and it will replace your html

Comment: I appreciate that information Sushil. I was scratching my head for a few minutes wondering what was going on haha, now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just add focus to the field after the `click` and then unbind the `click` event.

```
$('.thelink') + $('#143').on('click',function () {
    $('.main') + $('#143').html('<input type="text" id="pername143" /> <input type="button" value="Set Gift" id="submitgiftname" />');
    $('#pername143').focus();
    $(this).unbind('click');
});

$('.thelink') + $('#145').on('click',function () {
    $('.main') + $('#145').html('<input type="text" id="pername145" /> <input type="button" value="Set Gift" id="submitgiftname" />');
    $('#pername145').focus();
    $(this).unbind('click');
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZtMH/13/)

Answer (score 0):

You still have a click event on #143, #145, etc., so when you are clicking on the input, you are executing the onclick on the containing '.main' element again.

Perhaps try this:

```
$('.thelink').click(function() {
    var $container = $(this).closest('.main');
    var container_id = $container.attr('id');
    $container.html('<input type="text" id="pername'+container_id+'" /><input type="button" value="Set Gift" id="submitgiftname" />');
    $('#pername'+container_id).focus();
});
```

Note that using this method, you will not need a separate onclick handler for each link.

Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4ZtMH/17/

Answer (score 0):

The HTML syntax would be the same, but the link to assign the class as determined for the CLICK event. View demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/moizest89/6Fqrr/)

```
$('a.thelink','#143').click(function() {
   $('.main') + $('#143').html('<input type="text" id="pername143" /> <input type="button" value="Set Gift" id="submitgiftname" />');
});

$('a.thelink','#145').click(function() {
   $('.main') + $('#145').html('<input type="text" id="pername145" /> <input type="button" value="Set Gift" id="submitgiftname" />');
});
```